# Dymola Initialization failed

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'm trying to use the importInitialResult command to set initial values from old results. After doing this, I press the simulate button and receive the following error:

```
The boundary mass fractions in medium "AirNOW" in model "FixedBoundary"
do not sum up to 1. Instead, sum(X_boundary) = 1:
   X_boundary[1] = 0.005 "H2O"
   X_boundary[2] = 0.23 "O2"
   X_boundary[3] = 0.765 "N2"
```

it does not make sensse since 0.005 + 0.23 + 0.765 equal 1. I cound not figure out why i get this eror and how to make it correct.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to fully answer this without the full model, but the error message and using `importInitialResult` suggests one explanation:

- The sum seems to be 1 and the error message indicates that as well.
- The simplest explanation is thus that the sum is almost but not quite 1

It should be possible to avoid this by any of the following:

- Store the result (that you import with importInitialResult`) in double precision, Simulation>Setup>Output>Format>Double precision
- Use a less strict check for 1 in `AirNOW`-model
- Use some of the reduced-states-variants where you don't specify the last element of `X_boundary` but instead compute it as `1-sum(X_boundary[1:..])`

Added:

Without the example model I tried importInitialResult for Modelica.Fluid.Examples.TraceSubstances.RoomCO2:

- Without double precision it failed with the same error message as in the question
- With double precision, but not storing protected variables it sometimes failed with index out of bounds for `traceVolume.CVec[traceVolume.ind]` - that is somewhat specific for this example; but in general protected variables can be a problem.
- Storing double precision and protected variables it worked

Note that those changes must be done before the first simulation, so that importInitialResult reads from such a result file. The GUI for importInitialResult will show warnings if the result file doesn't contain all variables in double precision.

Comment: a. I tried to use double precision .mat file to initialize, but it failed. I received the same error.

b. I could not change the check condition because the function checkBoundary is defined in Modelida.Fluid.Utilities.

c. I have already used 1 - sum(X). It seems, it does not work

Comment: Do you need importInitialResult or would it be possible to use importInitial ? Then you could delete the values for X_boundary[:] from the dsfinal file before executing the command and see what happens.